# Facebook login crash with no error (Parse.com) android

Tags: java, android, facebook, parse-platform

My app crashes when I am trying to login with parse.com facebook login. I tried to debug and found out that the code never gets the callback, here is the login code:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(thisActivity, new LogInCallback() {
                  @Override
                  public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                    if (user == null) { // the code never gets here
                      Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    } else if (user.isNew()) {
                      Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                    } else {
                      Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                    }
                  }
                });
```

here is the logcat (couldn't find any error):

```
06-24 21:04:39.760: D/dalvikvm(2634): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 80K, 7% free 2612K/2796K, paused 26ms, total 28ms
06-24 21:04:39.760: I/dalvikvm-heap(2634): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.107MB for 480016-byte allocation
06-24 21:04:39.830: D/dalvikvm(2634): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 3080K/3268K, paused 64ms, total 64ms
06-24 21:04:39.850: D/dalvikvm(2634): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3082K/3268K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 23ms
06-24 21:04:39.990: D/libEGL(2634): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
06-24 21:04:39.990: E/(2634): file /data/data/com.nvidia.NvCPLSvc/files/driverlist.txt: not found!
06-24 21:04:39.990: I/(2634): Attempting to load EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
06-24 21:04:40.000: I/(2634): Loaded EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
06-24 21:04:40.000: D/libEGL(2634): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
06-24 21:04:40.000: D/libEGL(2634): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
06-24 21:04:40.060: I/(2634): Loading GLESv2 implementation /system/lib//egl/libGLESv2_tegra_impl
06-24 21:04:40.060: D/OpenGLRenderer(2634): Enabling debug mode 0
06-24 21:04:40.390: D/dalvikvm(2634): GC_CONCURRENT freed 247K, 10% free 3257K/3608K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 25ms
06-24 21:04:40.940: D/TextView(2634): Constructor - Got Res id for appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
06-24 21:04:40.940: W/ResourceType(2634): Skipping entry 0x1060001 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
06-24 21:04:40.940: D/TextView(2634): Constructor - Got appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
06-24 21:04:40.940: D/TextView(2634): Constructor -- Got mEditTextBackgroundColor
06-24 21:04:40.970: D/TextView(2634): Constructor - Got Res id for appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
06-24 21:04:40.970: W/ResourceType(2634): Skipping entry 0x1060001 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
06-24 21:04:40.970: D/TextView(2634): Constructor - Got appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
06-24 21:04:40.970: D/TextView(2634): Constructor -- Got mEditTextBackgroundColor
06-24 21:04:40.990: D/dalvikvm(2634): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 222K, 9% free 3381K/3708K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
06-24 21:04:40.990: I/dalvikvm-heap(2634): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.858MB for 480016-byte allocation
06-24 21:04:41.010: D/dalvikvm(2634): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 3849K/4180K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
06-24 21:04:41.030: D/dalvikvm(2634): GC_CONCURRENT freed 32K, 9% free 3818K/4180K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 16ms
06-24 21:04:41.050: D/dalvikvm(2634): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 3818K/4180K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
06-24 21:04:41.050: I/dalvikvm-heap(2634): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.285MB for 480016-byte allocation
06-24 21:04:41.060: D/dalvikvm(2634): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 4287K/4652K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
06-24 21:04:41.080: D/dalvikvm(2634): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 4287K/4652K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 15ms
```

**EDIT**
**EDIT:**
I think I found the source of the problem, when I am trying to access the declaration of `logIn` of `ParseFacebookUtils` I am getting this page: Class File editor (`the jar of this class file belongs to container 'android dependencies' which does not allow modification to source attachments on its entries.`).
Also I have updated my parse sdk version from 1.2.4 to 1.3 by deleting the old sdk from libs and adding the new one with it's content (total of 4 files and folder).

Why the app crashes? why there is no error?? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my Manifest (some wrong properties).

Comment: hi, i am getting the same error, could you pls kindly tell what have you amended / added in the manifest?

Comment: @pearmak I don't have the old code. Try to check your manifest. Post new question with your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear logcat/clear project and restart eclipse, sometimes thats the reason that no error is being shown up